# Processing modeler in QGIS 3.16: connection line and wedge buffer for several points

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-modeler, expression

I would like to automate two tasks using the processing modeler of QGIS 3.16. The two layers A (shown in blue) and B (orange) consists of point geometries. They should be used as input by the user and have an unknown data model.

Step 1: The first task is to create a line (output=linestring) between all the points of layer A to all the points of layer B (n:n relationship). I thought of the tool "distance to the nearest hub", but then only the nearest point would be included and not all the points of B. The tool "hub lines" from vector analysis doesn't seem appropriate to me either, because the data model of the input is too diverse.

Step 2: In the next step a wedge buffer should be generated. The connecting lines from step 1 should be used as the respective azimuth. As input I will use all geometries of point A. Wedge with = 30 degrees, inner radius = 1000 meters and outer radius = 2000 meters.

In the picture you can see the result of two points from layer A to one point from layer B. In addition to the other points from layer B, I want to have a connection line and a wedge buffer created.

[image]

Do you have some hints for me? How can I address the geometry of all features of two different layers (e.g. with collecting by aggregate)?